# What do I use for a return type when I am returning data from an anonymous class with Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have the following ASP MVC4 code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult GetTestAccounts(int applicationId)
    {
        var testAccounts =
            (
                from testAccount in this._testAccountService.GetTestAccounts(3)
                select new
                {
                    Id = testAccount.TestAccountId,
                    Name = testAccount.Name
                }
            ).ToList();

        return Json(testAccounts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now I am converting this to work with Web API. For this can someone tell me
what my return type should be if I am returning an anonymous class as here?

Comment: I would 'wrap' this function and let it return a strong named type. The other end can interpret that type when its serializable. With wrapping you do not have to edit the code inside the application that exposes the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be an `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public class TestAccountsController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int applicationId)
    {
        var testAccounts =
            (
                from testAccount in this._testAccountService.GetTestAccounts(3)
                select new 
                {
                    Id = testAccount.TestAccountId,
                    Name = testAccount.Name
                }
            ).ToList();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, testAccounts);
    }
}
```

But good practices dictate that you should use view models (as you should have done in your ASP.NET MVC application as well by the way):

```
public class TestAccountViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class TestAccountsController: ApiController
{
    public List<TestAccountViewModel> Get(int applicationId)
    {
        return
            (
                from testAccount in this._testAccountService.GetTestAccounts(3)
                select new TestAccountViewModel 
                {
                    Id = testAccount.TestAccountId,
                    Name = testAccount.Name
                }
            ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PabloRomeo, yes, that's exactly how it should read. Thanks for spotting that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I agree that if you are going to return a type other than `HttpResponseMessage` then it absolutely should be some kind of view model, however I do not agree that it is a best practice over returning `HttpResponseMessage`, it is just a different style of using Web API.